# Wrong file path.. VS code, Shopify Liquid Extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, shopify, themes

This is probably a newbie question, but I've been developing a Shopify theme and ended up putting it down for sometime. When I've come back in I've noticed all my files such as {{ 'theme.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }} are getting an error saying 'assets/theme.css' does not exist theme-check

and I've noticed I'm getting theme check errors on  the section bit of code written with section.settings such as below even though the it is located in the sections folder and is a .liquid file.

Its clearly crazy because even when I run shopify theme dev and test my theme it all functions correctly, and if I were to edit the file it's apparently unable to find the changes display while running theme dev.

When I command click the name such as theme.css it prompts me to create a file and I noticed the breadcrumbs are showing a strange path such as users > username > assets > theme.css when the folder is really in desktop > Theme Folder

I'm simply accessing the folder by either clicking on the workspace file I've made in the past or by opening up visual studio and opening up the root folder for the theme. So I have no idea why it's targeting my Users > username directory.

Is there a simple way to fix this? I've searched the way but all the solutions seem to be way above my head.

Thanks so much

re downloading shopify CLI and VS code. Uninstalling and re installing shopify liquid extension, try an older version of shopify liquid extension.

I'd literally pay someone to resolve this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxgB9.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqVMm.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YS02S.png